# How would I debug Flex 3 databinding?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, actionscript

I'm trying to connect a datagrid to an HTTPService via a simple external XML document, and this is failing. How would I go about debugging where the problem is arising?

I'm using the following:

`<mx:HTTPService id = "licenseService" resultFormat="e4x" url="http://localhost/licenseTest.xml" />`

with

`<mx:DataGrid horizontalCenter="0" width="476" top="50" dataProvider="{licenseService.lastResult.license}">`

I'm relatively new to flex, so basic help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've checked that http://localhost/licenseTest.xml when viewed in a browser returns the expected XML?

Comment: Yes, but that's a good question at any rate. As it turns out, I had forgotten to call send() on the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add result event handler for HTTP Service:

```
<mx:HTTPService id = "licenseService" resultFormat="e4x" url="http://localhost/licenseTest.xml" result="licenseService_resultHandler(event)" />
```

And define the handler inside `<mx:Script>`:

```
private function licenseService_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    trace("Result:", event.result);
}
```

You can place a breakpoint inside this method and start debugging the data that comes from the server